# How can I convert a daily dateframe to a weekly one (for one column)?

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I'm getting stocks data from Quandl. I've daily volumes and I want to find the weekly ones.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.today()
stocks = ["WIKI/AAPL", "WIKI/TSLA", "WIKI/IBM", "WIKI/LNKD"]
key = ...
df = data.DataReader(stocks, "quandl", start, end, api_key=key)
vol = df['Volume']

# now I want to Aggregate the data of Volume to weekly, I tried this but it doesn't work:
vol['week'] = vol.index.week
vol['year'] = vol.index.year

week = vol.groupby(['week','year']).sum()
week.head()
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Show us a sample of your data, for example `print(df.head())` and what your expected output is.

Comment: How can I show the output? (sorry I'm not already familiar with this stuff)

Answer (score 0):

More like this.

```py
df_week = df.groupby(['week','year'])["Volume"].sum()
```